# three point data in a scatter chart HighChart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am displaying a scatter chart using highchart. 
Data provide to the high chart is in format

```
[
    obj1 : [
              {
                 "x":"0.1",
                 "y":"12",
                 "id":"154"
              },....
           ],....
]
```

The graph draws properly on x an y axis.

my issue is i want to be able to use the third value id when i click any point but it is not visible in the point. i have tried to print out the point object it does not have any sort of object named id.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: can you add this to a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

use [plotOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click) click event

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        align: 'left',
        enabled: false,
        format: '{point.id}',

      },
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            alert('Id: ' + this.id);
          }
        }
      }
    }

  },
```

Assuming that your series data is like

```
data: [
    {x:161.2,y:51.6,id:154},{x:100.2,y:60.6,id:155},{x:161.2,y:151.6,id:157}]

}]
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0eujzp4u/)

Answer (score 0):

```
series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            // here I want the y value of the point in the
                            // first series even in this function 
                            // is invoked for the point in the second series
                            alert('value: ' + this);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please use this i think if you print this object it will give you all the points which you are passing inside the series.

Comment: even OP has not provided any live demo(fiddle,plunker etc). Can you add example to show what you explained.